# Access last line while using UILineBreakModeWordWrap UILabel in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

I am displaying a long string using `UILabel` with `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`. It is showing the string perfectly by wrapping text in `UILabel`. I want to access last line of `UILabel`. Does anyone know how to do this on an iPhone?

Comment: is this long string a static string or dynamic? if it was dynamic you could use something like 'NSString *lastLine = [longString substringFromIndex:[longString length]-35/*lets say you know the last line length is 35*/]' and display the 'lasLine' as a UITextField wich is editable

Comment: long string is dynamic, and I don't know the length of last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried some stuff and searched a little around. What you wuld actually need is to count the word wraps and somehow detect the last string. But I didnt really figuere out how to do that.

So my sollution is something like this:

Your String `//I googled some longer String`

```
 NSString *string = @"Standing across the room, I saw you smile\nSaid I want to talk to you-oo-oo for a little while\nBut before I make my move my emotions start running wild\nMy tongue gets tied and that's no lie\nLooking in your eyes\nLooking in you big brown eyes ooh yeah\nAnd I've got this to say to you\nHey!\nGirl I want to make you sweat\nSweat till you can't sweat no more\nAnd if you cry out\nI'm gonna push it some, more, more\nGirl I want to make you sweat\nSweat till you can't sweat no more\nAnd if you cry out\nI'm gonna push it\nPush it, push it some more";
```

Your Label:

```
UILabel *label          = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 440)];
label.font              = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
label.lineBreakMode     = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines     = 0;
label.backgroundColor   = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor         = [UIColor blackColor];
label.text              = string;
```

The call this Method:

```
NSString *result = [self getLastLineFromString:string];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```

`getLastLineFromString:` looks like this:

```
- (NSString *)getLastLineFromString: (NSString *)string{
    NSArray *a = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *result = [a objectAtIndex:[a count]-1];
    NSString *temp = @"";
    int count = 1;
    BOOL myBool = YES;
    while (myBool) {
        count++;

        temp = result;
        result = [a objectAtIndex:[a count] -count];
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", result, temp];
        NSLog(@"length: %i",[self lengthOfString:result]);
        NSLog(@"result: %@",result);

    //131 was a value i detected mayels, i guess u have do trick a little around to find a mathcing one for yourself
    if ([self lengthOfString:result] >= 131) {
        myBool = NO;
    }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And The Method`lengthOfString:` looks like this:

```
- (int)lengthOfString:(NSString *)string{
    CGSize size1 = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];
    return size1.width;
}
```

Output:

```
2012-01-06 16:17:08.341 get length[5472:207] result: it
Push it, push it some more
```

I know this is not a perfect sollution, but it might help you.